# Undefined index: values in _civicrm_api3_api_resolve_alias()

Tags: civimail, drupal, mailing

I'm using a new installed CiviCRM 4.7.8. with Drupal 7.5  ( Database system version 5.7.12-0ubuntu1 - PHP   5.6.22-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1  )

The installation was done without errors but now I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: values in _civicrm_api3_api_resolve_alias() (line 2310 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in _civicrm_api3_api_resolve_alias() (line 2317 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php).
Notice: Undefined index: values in _civicrm_api3_api_resolve_alias() (line 2310 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in _civicrm_api3_api_resolve_alias() (line 2317 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php).
```

on clicking "New Mailing".

Any idea what's wrong or how to solve this error?

Thank you

Comment: I had this when sending test mailings. An error popup showed "DBError: Unknown error". Digging in to the debug and log info showed "[nativecode=1055 ** ...

Answer (score 1):

```
[debug_info] => SELECT id, component_type
                FROM    civicrm_mailing_component
                WHERE   is_active = 1
                AND     is_default = 1
                GROUP BY component_type [nativecode=1055 ** Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'civicrm.civicrm_mailing_component.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by]
```

After deactivating 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' in mysql with

```
msql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

it works...

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18439

Comment: Helped my problem too. Accepting your own answer is possible and will give you some more points ;-)